# SQL to extend dates and convert to format Monday, February 20, 2017 OR Excel function

Tags: sql, excel, date, casting

I have a SQL that is selecting a beginning and ending date. I need to create output that shows all the dates of that range in format of DayName, MonthName dd, yyyy and here's the twist...in UPPERCASE.

I've been searching, but all of the answers I find, I believe are overly cumbersome.

OR...
is there a way in Excel to format to format in uppercase?
Once I format the date field to DayName, MonthName dd, yyyy, it does not allow me to do an =UPPER() function. I'd prefer to do it all with SQL though.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is a way in Excel to make a formatted date uppercase, but you can use a formula to turn a date into a text value, then make it uppercase, as in `=UPPER(TEXT(NOW(),"dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy"))` -- just replace "NOW()" with a date or a cell reference that contains a date.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I was able to do what you requested with this

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '20120101',
        @MaxDate DATE = '20140101';
with cte (testDate)
as(
SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
        Date =  DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate)
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b
)

select  
UPPER(CAST(DATENAME(dw, testDate)as varchar(10)) + ', ' +
        CAST(DATENAME(MM, testDate) as varchar(10)) 
        + ' ' + CAST(DAY(testDate) as varchar(2))
        + ', ' + CAST(YEAR(testDate) as varchar(4))) as test
        FROM cte
```

EDIT:
For vknowles
This is another way that you could get the same results without using the cross join in the cte.

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '20120101',
        @MaxDate DATE = '20140101';

WITH cte (testDate) AS
(
  SELECT CAST(@MinDate as DATETIME) as testDate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  testDate + 1
  FROM    cte   
  WHERE   testDate + 1 <= @MaxDate
)

select  
UPPER(CAST(DATENAME(dw, testDate)as varchar(10)) + ', ' +
        CAST(DATENAME(MM, testDate) as varchar(10)) 
        + ' ' + CAST(DAY(testDate) as varchar(2))
        + ', ' + CAST(YEAR(testDate) as varchar(4))) as test
        FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: @jonathan - I think I parsed this and understand how it works, but I have a question. Not sure if I should open a new question, but here it is: I assume your cross join of all_objects to itself is intended solely to create a large row space that you then use to create as many date entries as you need. What if you have a small database and a large date range, so this cross join doesn't produce enough rows? (I realize this unlikely.)

Comment: I'll admit I hadn't considered that. I'll edit my answer to include another way.

Comment: @Jonathan - That is a clever approach. After some research, I found that it depends on (at least) two implementation-specific features: (1) `SELECT` without `FROM` and (2) recursive processing. For example, ORACLE requires a `FROM` clause and provides the "DUAL" table for dummy purposes. SAS PROC SQL doesn't really provide either feature, though you can fudge (1). But, still, a good example.